# Pyspark add new record to each Row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm using Spark 2.3.1. I'm reading data from json file and there are five records of **<class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>** type like

> Row(age=24, payloadId=1, salary=2900)

I want to add a new value in all five records, new value is in Dictionary format like this

```
{'age_condition':True,'salary_condition':True}
```

so, now new Row should be like this

> Row(age=24, payloadId=1, salary=2900, Result={'age_condition':True,'salary_condition':True})

Answer (score 0):

What about this way? Be aware that the `Result` column is treated as string type not dict.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

row_list = [Row(age=24, payloadId=1, salary=2900)]
row_add = {'age_condition':True,'salary_condition':True}

spark.createDataFrame(row_list) \
  .withColumn('Result', f.lit(str(row_add))) \
  .collect()

[Row(age=24, payloadId=1, salary=2900, Result="{'age_condition': True, 'salary_condition': True}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to complicate things by adding dictionaries into dataframe column,you should add two new columns `age_condition` and `salary_condition` of boolean type instead.

#### This should do what you want...

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField("dict", StructType([StructField("age_condition", BooleanType(), True), StructField("salary_condition", BooleanType(), True)]), True)])

newDf = spark.createDataFrame([{'age_condition':True,'salary_condition':True}], schema=schema)

df = spark.read.json("/whatever/json/path")

df.crossJoin(newDf) #no of records is same as in df as no of records in newDf is 1
```